# Solving a complicated ODE numerically using Python

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python

I have an equation that goes like this:
$$\phi'' + \left(3-\frac{\phi'^2}{2}\right) \left(\phi' + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\left( \frac{e^{-\sqrt{2/3}\phi}}{1 - e^{-\sqrt{2/3}\phi}}\right)\right) = 0$$

Is there a way to solve this numerically using Python? I tried using `dsolve` from `sympy`, but wasn't able to get much out of it. Is there any numerical method that is either built-in/can be manually implemented which can be used to solve it?

Comment: The numerical ODE solvers are in `scipy.integrate`, use the pendulum example as basis for a second order equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scipy.integrate.ode(). The equation you propose can be written as a system of first order equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\phi' = \psi\\
\psi'=\left(\frac{\psi^2}{2}-3\right)\left(\psi+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\left(\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\frac 23 \phi}}}{1-e^{-\sqrt{\frac 23 \phi}}}\right)\right)
\end{cases}
$$